# Sprintf duplicate value

Tags: php, printf

Here's a quick question

I need to duplicate values in a sprintf function

```
sprintf("%s %s %s",$arg1,$arg1,$arg2);
```

How can I only pass $arg1 once? Can't seem to find the answer on php.net
Thanks
Andrew

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the indexed format `%1$s` instead:

```
sprintf("%1$s %1$s %2$s", $arg1, $arg2)
```