# PHP sprintf - using the same value multiple times?

Tags: php

I use the sprintf function as follows:

```
sprintf( '
        .site-footer {
            border-top-color : %s;
        }
', $fys_color_base_1 );
```

What I want to achieve is:

```
sprintf( '
        .site-footer {
            border-top-color : %s;
        }
        .site-wrapper {
            background-color : %s;
        }
', $fys_color_base_1 );
```

But this is not working - how do I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Some other dups: [dup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674058/sprintf-repeating-arguments) **&&** [dup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4298341/sprintf-duplicate-value). Note that I googled your title

Answer (score 33, accepted):

According to the docs for [`sprintf`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php), simply use argument swapping (Example [#3](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php#example-6130)):

```
sprintf( '
        .site-footer {
            border-top-color : %1$s;
        }
        .site-wrapper {
            background-color : %1$s;
        }
', $fys_color_base_1 );
```

Comment: It appears that now it is example #1, at the very end of it